# Regular expression to find unmatched words in string

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want to achieve?

->Replace the words from the string that does not match a regular expression, and replace it with some other text.

I am not that good with regexps though, so it would be great if you help me out.

For example:

```
var str = "New York";
alert(str.replace(/some_magical_reg_ex/, "Jersey"));
```

So I want to "New", and replace the word "York" with something else. The outcome should be "New Jersey";

What I have tried?

https://regex101.com/r/fQ9fN8/3 With respect to this, I want to highlight the word 'angeles', so I could replace it with some other word.

Notice the last line from the example. Input given is 'los angeles', but none is highlighted/matched.

If you think I am missing any inputs, please let me know, I will update the question accordingly.

**EDIT:**
Let me try to explain more.

I have a dropdown, which shows locations. So if a user enters 'Lo', it will display following options. Louisiana, Los Angeles etc(whichever starts with 'Lo').
So in this list, I need to apply `<b></b>` tags for the remaining part of the texts. 
i.e when user enters 'Lo', show

- 'Lo**uisiana**'
- 'Lo**s Angeles**'

So in the case of `str.replace(/some_magical_reg_ex/, <b>unmatched_text</b>)`

str = 'Lo' (user input) and
unmatched_text = 'uisiana' or 's Angeles'

Comment: `/^(?!los).*/gim` matches any line that does not start with `los` - what do you need to achieve? The example in your question can be solved with just `replace(/\bYork\b/, "Jersey")`

Comment: Regular expressions are for matching patterns, you haven't really well defined the pattern you're trying to match. Do you just want to match the word following `New` or `Los`? Is it a single prefix you're looking for or a list?

Comment: What is known in your case? "New" or "York"?

Comment: I believe now that you need [`/\b(?!New\b)\w+\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1aI5/1).

Comment: Maybe this is working `^((\w).*? )\w+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated the question. Please see edit. Thank you for your inputs so far.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex and non regex way to match text followed by the user input:

```js
var options = ["lousiana", 'los angeles', 'another']

var userInput = "lo"

options.forEach(function(val){
    if(val.indexOf(userInput) == 0){
      console.log(val.replace(new RegExp('('+userInput+')(.*)', 'gi'), "$1<b>$2</b>"))  
    }
})

options.forEach(function(val){
  var idx = val.indexOf(userInput)
  if(idx == 0){
    console.log(userInput+'<b>'+val.substring(userInput.length)+'</b>')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a word that follows a specific word, use a positive lookbehind :

```
(?<=New )\w+
```

This will match the "Jersey" in "New Jersey".

Looking at your provided example, it looks like you want to match the rest of a line starting with a specific word. I'd use this :

```
^(?<=los ).*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
/^Lo(.*)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1aI5/1)

Replace with `Lo<b>$1</b>`.

Here is a way to use it in a dynamic pattern:

```js
var knownWord = 'Lo';
var subst = knownWord + '<b>$1</b>'; 
var re = RegExp("^" + knownWord + "(.*)", "i"); 
var result = 'Los Angeles'.replace(re, subst);
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: If I type 'New York', the full word 'New York' is matched . Whereas I want only the term ' York' to be matched.

Comment: What do you mean? If you know the string and type it fully, you should get the whole entry match. Please clarify. A fiddle would be very helpful to understand what you mean.